# Can not Upload Image from Form to Django Admin Model

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, file-upload

I am trying to upload a Image from my Form (signup.html) and then i want that uploaded image name/url to be shown at Django admin models panel too. so i can access the image that user uploaded from the django admin panel.
image upload feature is working in Django panel but when i upload it from my Form . my django admin is not saving it . it is also not saving any information like(email, bio,image).

i already tried some solutions from stackoverflow but it didn't work.

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CustomerForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Profile


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            bio = form.cleaned_data.get('bio')
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account is created. ')
            return redirect('signin')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
    return render(request, 'Authentication/signup.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def UserAuth(request):
    return render(request, 'Authentication/profile.html')
```

This is my forms.py below

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import *


class CustomerForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Preferred first Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Preferred Last Name')
    email = forms.EmailField()
    image = forms.ImageField()
    bio = forms.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'image', 'bio', 'password1', 'password2')
```

and this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', default='default.jpg', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Signup</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<main role="main" class="container">
<h2>Sign up Form</h2>

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                    Join today
                </legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline" type="submit">SignUp</button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="border-top pt-3">
                <small class="text-muted">Already registered with us? please Signin
                    <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'signin' %}">SignIn</a>
                </small>
            </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock content %}
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-md-offset-6">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Something more?</h3>
              <p class='text-muted'> Check out the latest tweets from elon.</p>
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Tweets</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Elon tweets?</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
</main>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

please help any help is appreciated

Comment: do you revicce any errors in your form? is this `if form.is_valid():` ever true? add `{{form.errors}}` to your html or print them in the terminal.

Comment: i tried with {{ form.error }} . it is not showing any error . when i click (signup) it just redirects me to next page (signin) buts still (bio, email , image ) is not saved at django admin model

Comment: its form.erorrs (with a s at the end) use some print statments or debugger in your views.py function to see where the code stops to narrow down the problem.

Comment: i tried with {{form.errors}} still can't get the problem fixed .

Comment: thats because User model has no image field by default. and You are not extending User model. 'Profile' has image field, the Signup form will create user in User model. as it dont have image field it wont save it. but will save other fields.

Comment: okay i see so how do i extend the user model ? do you have any example of how i can fix this